# How to optimize your code to pass some test cases

Tags: java

I was doing some questions on hackerrank and my code does pass some cases but did not pass all test cases, can someone help me with this question? Here is a screenshot of the question and part of my code

here is my code to the solution:

```
public static int mDivisor(List<Integer> arr, int threshold) {
        // arr = [1,5,7] threshold = 8
        // 1+ 5 + 7/ n < 8
        //1 + 5 + 7 < 8n
        // 13 < 8n
        // n = 1.625
        // n = 2
        // need more time to debug


        int minDivisor = 1;
        // find the minimum number to start division by based on our formula
        Optional<Integer> sArr = arr.stream().reduce((a,b)-> a+b);
        if(sArr.isPresent()){
            int sum = sArr.get();
            minDivisor = Math.round((float) sum/threshold);
        }

        // min greater should be greater than or equal to
        int totalSum; // to hold the value greater than the threshold
        do{
            totalSum = getSum(arr, minDivisor);
            if(totalSum > threshold){
                minDivisor += 1;
            }

        } while(totalSum > threshold);

        return minDivisor; // return the minDivisor

    }

    private static int getSum(List<Integer> a, int minDivisior){
        int t_sum = 0; // to hold total sum
        for(Integer n: a){
            t_sum += Math.round((float)n/minDivisior);
        }

        return t_sum; // return the total sum

    }
}
```

Sample small numbers for my threshold:

```
@Test


       public void minimumDivisor() {

            //int[] arr = {1,5,7};
            List<Integer> arr1 = Arrays.asList(1,10,15,19);
            int threshold = 5;
            int expectedOutput = 9;
            Assertions.assertEquals(expectedOutput , mDivisor(arr1,threshold));

        }
```

Comment: I assume you mean the test cases time out because your program is to slow to return a result? If so you'd better ask your question on [the CodeReview SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) which is more relevant when you want to improve working code.

Comment: are you sure about round the divisions? looking at the answer seems like you should use ceil, not round